# How to get tag from URL and display it with template tags (Django)

Tags: django

Is there a way to render a HTML and the content different based on the url so that I don't manually have to add a view to each one?

Maybe I explained it bad, I will show you with code:

```
url(r"^tag/<tag>/$", views.tag, name="tag"),
```

When I enter domain.com/tag/mytag it will render the HTML and `<h1>` with the tag.

So how do I in my view get the tag that the user entered to display them in the HTML template?

**My views.py:**

```
def tag(request):
    return render(request, "tag/tag.html")
```

Comment: Could you share your `views.py` file along with the corresponding HTML template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your url slightly.

```
url(r"^tag/(?P<tag>[\w-]+)/$", views.tag, name="tag"),
```

Then add tag to the kwargs in your view, and pass tag to the template context.

```
def tag(request, tag):
    return render(request, "tag/tag.html", {'tag': tag})
```

Note that tag will just be the text from the url.

This is a pretty basic question, you would probably find it useful to work through the tutorial which covers these parts of Django.

Answer (score 0):

you can use (?P ) to capture the text within the parenthesis and pass it as a parameter to your view automatically.

```
  url(r"^tag/(?P.*)/$", views.tag, name="tag"),

  def tag(request, tag):
        return render(request, "tag/tag.html")
```